# Jenkins Date, Time and module name in console output

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 Jenkins with same version 2.235 ( i know it is old but im stuck with this version).
In one Jenkins i see in maven job that it displays the date, time and the module in the console output, and in another it is not.

In both the plugins are exactly the the same. none of them has [Timestamper plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/), but yet one is displaying the info and the other is not.

See example:
[image]
What can i change to see it the “bad” Jenkins?

Comment: Pretty sure you need need to enable in the jobs **Configuration Bindings** ( `[ X ] Create a formatted version number` ) for freestyle jobs and in the **Global Configuration** ( `/configure` ) for Pipeline jobs.

Comment: and if i use maven project job?

Comment: Don't use [Maven job](https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-plugin/#plugin-content-risks) type. But probably a job binding option.

Comment: Unfortunately i have to use Maven Integration plugin and i do pass -Dcc.proj.version= param but still not getting the timestamp.
the issue is that in one jenkins it is working and other is not but both same version and same plugins folder

Comment: No one HAS TO use maven job type; you can build maven in a freestyle or pipeline job. When the Jenkins developer community specifically documents to discourage plugin use, you are on your own.